# Mobile application form using phonegap and firebase

Tags: javascript, cordova, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, phonegap

i am doing a mobile application survey form using phonegap and firebase.
My data from the form is inserted to firebase however it only work for textbox and not radio button. is there something wrong with my codes?
 This is what shown in firebase.[image: firebase]

The following is my code

```
          <form id="testForm">
          <b style="font-size: 27px;">Survey Form<p></p></b>
          <b class=fs>Name of client:</b> <br><input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
          <b class=fs>Date: </b><br><input type="date" name="date" id="date"><p></p>
      <b class=fs>1)Do you worry? In the past month?</b> <p>
          <input type="radio" name="q1" value="0" id="q1"> 0
          <input type="radio" name="q1" value="1" id="q1"> 1 <p>
      <b class=fs>2) Have you been sad or depressed in the past month?</b> <p>
          <input type="radio" name="q2" value="0" id="q2"> 0
          <input type="radio" name="q2" value="1" id="q2"> 1 <p>

      <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit">
  </form>

  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.2/firebase.js"></script>
  <script>

  //reference messages collection
  var testRef = firebase.database().ref('test');

  // listen for form submit
  document.getElementById('testForm').addEventListener('submit',submitForm);


  function submitForm(e){
    e.preventDefault();

      var name = getInputVal('name');
      var date = getInputVal('date');
      var q1  = getInputVal('q1');
      var q2  = getInputVal('q2');

  saveMessage(name,date,q1,q2);
  }

  function getInputVal(id){
    return document.getElementById(id).value;
  }

  function saveMessage(name,date,q1,q2){
    var newMessageRef = testRef.push();
    newMessageRef.set({
      screenby:name,
      date:date,
      q1:q1,
      q2:q2,
    });
  }
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: ID needs to be unique, since you are using `name`. Use `document.getElementsByClassName("example");` to access your values

Comment: ok i try firstt